# $O(N)$ symmetry in three dimensions

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, ferromagnetism, large-n

Recently, In a research article on magnetism, I came across the term

> "$O(N)$ symmetry for three dimensions with the limit $N->infinity$".

What does it mean? When I tried to search about it, could not find much in any Physics text/reference book. Although some Mathematics references on group theory have a discussion about it. But, I am more interested in getting the physical meaning of it. Will appreciate any explanation/reference about it. Is it a old convention symbol of any symmetry element or point/space group?

Comment: Could you point us to the specific article you were looking at so that we have some context?

Comment: Thanks. Yes. The article is "Scaling of hysteresis dispersion in model spin system" by Liu et al in PRB 2001.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the references your source is expressly sending you to, namely [Rao, M., Krishnamurthy, H. R., & Pandit, R. (1990): "Magnetic hysteresis in two model spin systems", *Physical Review*  **B42** (1) 856](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.42.856).

The three dimensions are spacetime dimensions, and *N* refers to the numbers of components in the vector representation of *O(N)*. So their fields $\Phi(x)^a$ live in a 3dim space indexed by *x*, and an internal ("spin") Ndim space indexed by the indices *a*, vectors rotating by the *N(N-1)/2* rotations of the O(N) group. In the large *N* limit, the structure of these models simplifies, as you probably [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/N_expansion), and their results follow.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this reference article as well. They also have pretty limited explanation to this term. Several other articles referred by these two articles (and having same authors) have pretty much same info.  Surprisingly, I failed to find any reference "independent" of this group of papers about O(N) symmetry. Will appreciate if you can suggest any independent source to it, preferably a book, as it would have more detailed explanation.

Comment: I gather you know [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9810198) by heart. If you needed more, try his legendary book.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it. Ah.. I just wanted to limit myself to magnetization....

Answer (score -3):

It's very simple. $O(N)$ is the group distance preserving transformations in a Euclidean space of $N$ dimensions. It's called the orthogonal group. Look for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) to find all relevant information. I'm not sure how the article on magnetism fits in here, but I think you know best yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I could also find the mathematical explanation to it, but want to understand its relevance for magnetic materials. Is it related to any symmetry element/point group ?

Comment: @user49535 In a continuous spin system, the continuity is modeled by letting the distance between the spins go to zero (N to infinity). If you perform the transformation, the system looks continuous.

Comment: Any reference to it ?

Comment: @user49535 No (not yet). It's only what I think.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if you find any. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @ maybe here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01220998

Comment: @user49535 Or here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38329963_On_the_continuous_limit_for_a_system_of_classical_spin/link/5545e5cb0cf24107d397d4ff/download  you can join for free